# Store: need {price} field to be optional?

Tags: expresso-store, add-on

I'm trying to set up an EE e-commerce site for the following scenario:

1. A product categories list that is 4 levels deep. The product categories will have at least two custom category fields: `amount` and `amount_type`. These fields represent the markup (profit) of a particular product associated with the category. Example values are: {10, 'percentage'} or {5, 'amount'}. NOTE: products will only be assigned the lowest level category.
2. The Channel that has the Store field will have a custom channel field `cost.` This represents the cost of the product to the retailer.
3. Optionally set the `price`.

In the frontend, I want customers to see this:

1. If the `price` field is populated, show that amount.
2. If the `price` field is not populated, then compute the selling price by using `cost` custom Channel field and `amount` and `amount_type` custom Categories fields.

As there is no requirement for the lowest level categories to actually have a value for `amount` and `amount_type`, the frontend logic would need to keep checking the parent category until it finds a category level that does have those fields populated. The root nodes will always be populated.

It appears that `price` is required, though. **So, what might I be able to do in order to support this custom business logic?** Perhaps I set the price to an invalid value, like `-1` and do checks in the frontend based on that somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store 2.x allows for user defined prices so you should be able to enter 0 in the price field then create some template logic when the price is 0 you would then run the math to get the correct price based upon your custom fields.

Comment: Well, I think a price of `0` would be a valid amount (meaning, free). So, I guess my `-1` idea might work? Will Store allow me to define the price in the frontend? Basically letting me override what was entered in the Store field?